# Make footer stick to bottom of body without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html

something's been bothering me for a while, and it's getting say a footer to be always at the bottom of the page.

```
<div id="one"> one</div>
<div id="two"> two</div>
<div id="three"> three</div>
```

in order to to make #three always be at the bottom are my only options making #two 100% height or absolutely positioning #three?

I'd like the footer to always be at the bottom of the window/body. If the page scrolls, the footer is NOT sticky.

Comment: When you say "stick to the bottom" do you want #two to scroll behind it if the combination of #one and #two are taller than the browser window is tall and do you want blank space inserted between #two and #three if they are shorted than the window is tall?

Comment: the latter. I i used position fixed, it one and two would scroll underneath, and so should I use absolute, so it's kinda more in the normal flow?

Comment: As LavaSlider asked, do you want #three to be at the bottom of the window or the bottom of the document?
Or bottom of the window for a short page and bottom of the document for a long page?

Comment: The latter. Bottom of window on short and of document kn long

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox to achieve this easily

Your HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="content">
  content
 </div>
 <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Your CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Read more about this topic: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score -1):

You can with `position: fixed` look the example

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: overline;  
    color: #999;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/r0rd1nrg/)